# Does Infrared Therapy relieve the symptoms of Carpal Tunnel Syndrome?

Tags: medical-science

I happened upon [Prolotex™ OPEN FINGERTIP Far Infrared Therapy Gloves](http://www.therapygloves.com/store/product.php?productid=2)

> 3/4 or Open Fingertip Far Infrared bio-ceramic gloves are helping reduce hand pain in all kinds of people: people, like you and me, who suffer from finger joint pain that sometimes keeps us awake at night.
>
> If you suffer from Trigger Thumb or Trigger Finger, these gloves are for you. Why? Because the natural FIR energy actually reduces the inflammation of the tendon sheath that is causing the your fingers to snap, crackle and pop!

Is there an evidence backing these claims? Do these gloves provide any benefit that basic application of heat would not?

[More information (theirs) on FIR](http://www.therapygloves.com/farinfrared.html)

Comment: [Miraculous Biogenetic Energy!](http://www.therapygloves.com/farinfrared.html)

Comment: infrared is really just heat, it would have the same effect as a heatpack

Comment: @ratchetfreak I've updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: "Trigger finger" is not CTS, although both can be a form of repetitive strain injuries (RSIs) and the same underlying problem (inflamed tendons) can cause both. The primary symptom of CTS is digital numbness, particular at night. The primary symptom of trigger finger is involuntary finger movements and pain. Is the question about CTS specifically, or RSI generally? (I doubt the answer matters, but...)

Comment: @JoeWreschnig RSI generally (if there's any provable medical benefit that wouldn't be provided by heat alone I'll be very surprised!)